# How to filter by unordered array comparison in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, monk

I have a "talks" collection that looks like this :

```
{ _id: "t1", participants: ["u4", "u2", "u1"] },
{ _id: "t2", participants: ["u2", "u6"] },
{ _id: "t3", participants: ["u2", "u1", "u9", "u5"] },
...
```

When a user wants to start a new "talk", he selects a set of users, and I want the server to check if a talk with these users already exists. That means unordered array equality check between two user sets.

I spent the last two hours on Google trying to find the answer and couldn't get it. Every operator seems to do something just slightly different from what I want. I tried something that seems ugly : checking if one set is included in the other, and vice versa :

```
Talks.find({ $and: [
  { participants: { $all: receiversId } },
  { $not: { participants: { $nin: receiversId } } }
]})
```

Is this correct ? What would be the best way to do this check ?

Comment: Something like `Talks.find(
  { participants: { $all: receiversId }, $size:length of input array }
)` For equality you should also include the size of array.

Comment: Nop, because it allows "participants" to have elements that are not in "receiversId". Edit : Thanks for your edit, that works !

Comment: Shouldn't the $size operator be applied to the "participants" field ?

Comment: Yes it is typo. Try `Talks.find( { participants: { $all: receiversId , $size:length of receiversId array }} )`